# Firebase import error

Tags: android, firebase

Before giving negative give such reason. So I will go for same.

Getting error while importing project from google to Firebase. I had import another project successfully from same account.

[image: Error screen]

Comment: you project name may by already copyright by some other company

Comment: I am owner of the account, can you please let me know how can i check your concern? @VishalPatoliyaツ

Comment: what is project name you trying to add?

Comment: I am just choosing the existing project from the projects list.@DivyeshPatel

Comment: then change name in google project

Comment: Since you're not saying anything about the specific project, it'll be hard to help here. I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems better targeted at Firebase support/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename project name from google console -> project settings.